# Supplement for those who with lactose intolerance?

Tags: substitutions, milk

Many people have lactose intolerance.

Is there a food or supplement that can be consumed with milk that can prevent diarrhea?

- Suppose lactose-free milk or soy milk, etc is not an available option.

### Edit

I learned that there is something like Lactaid.
But I wonder if it can be done by food rather than drug.

Suppose I invite guests and serve food including milk.
Some guests might have lactose intolerance.
The guest might not notice that the food contains milk.

I can tell them that the food contains milk and you may or may not have lactose intolerance, so if you do, please take the Lactaid. --> This sounds really funny.

That is the reason I'm looking for food that can substitute Lactaid.

Comment: Welcome to SA!  Unfortunately, as a request for medical advice, your question is off-topic for our board.   That said ... look up "Lactaid".

Comment: @FuzzyChef Thank you for your helpful comment. I edit my question and added explanation about the situation.

Comment: ...you inquire (at the time of inviting, or on arrival if a more spontaneous event) if guests have any food allergies. To do otherwise is to be a poor host, since some allergies can kill your guests, if you serve them food with an allergen they are sensitized to without informing them.

Comment: @user67275 Feeding people food without asking about their dietary restrictions isn't really terribly consistent with "kindness, collaboration, and mutual respect" or "inclusive and respectful". I'm going to wipe the comments, but please be open to the feedback that it may be your approach here that warrants adjusting, not your ingredients.

Comment: @Cascabel having an answer on there that’s “don’t poison your guests” is useful to be able to point to.  Most people with dairy issues will ask about the meal, and either bring lactaid or decline to eat.  The problem is when someone who knows your issues and has for more than a decade decides ‘oh, but it was cooked, I didn’t think that counted’ or ‘but it was only a little bit of cheese’ as your mom keeps asking why you don’t visit more often

Comment: @Joe Feel free to ask and self-answer a question. I'm happy to have info about how to handle dietary restrictions on the site, but I'd rather it'd be attached to a question that's asking for that, rather than asking how to feed your guests things that are harmful to them.

Answer (score 1):

There are many replacements for milk, so if you know that you will have guests that can’t consume milk, you can avoid it.

There are many plant based mills, typically made from either nuts (almond, coconut, cashew), beans (soy), or grains (rice, oat).  Beware that canned coconut milk has existed since before the fad existed.  You’ll want to use ‘coconut milk beverage’ as a direct replacement.

Canned coconut milk (not coconut cream) makes a decent substitute for cream in baking and cooking, except for making whipped cream.

Dairy-free cheese is getting better, and nutritional yeast often works as a replacement for grated cheeses like Parmesan.  I’d recommend looking for opinions online, as some may make good sandwiches but not melt well and visa-versa.

I haven’t tried any of the yogurt or sour cream alternatives, but I know they exist.

But I’d really recommend that unless you have a family recipe that you’re trying to adapt, that you just look online for a dairy-free variant of whatever you’re trying to make.

Also note that people who have issues with milk might not be lactose intolerant.  There are other substances (such as casein) in milk that people can have issues with.  That’s why I’m recommending avoiding dairy entirely, as some yogurts and hard cheeses have been fermented enough that lactose (a sugar) is greatly reduced.

Comment: Does the OP want to rush a guest to the ER for a shot of epinephrine or end the evening with somebody puking there guts out? If not make a vegan meal.

Comment: @NeilMeyer Lactose intolerance isn’t an allergy.  Intolerance may result in major gastrointestinal issues (gas and cramping in mild cases, spending the next two days in the bathroom in a bad case).  And it might not trigger until your next meal, making it a pain in the ass to try to figure out what triggered it.  (And I’m speaking from experience; doctors misdiagnosed me, and told me to eat more fiber, so I had high fiber cereal every morning… with milk)

Comment: @Joe Did he say lactose intolerance?  Milk allergies do exist.

Comment: @Edward he asked about prevention of diarrhea and mentioned Lactaid.  That’s intolerance.  Allergies would be throat constricting from anaphylaxis.  That being said, I’m intolerant to milk, but it’s casein, so lactaid doesn’t do anything,